# Problem with Firebase Realtime Database Rules "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid" not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase Realtime database and I want user to enter data only when the are logged in with their user ID.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Posts2":{
      ".read":true,
      ".write": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

Added this rule and it is not working I am using **Rules Playground** but it's showing error.

***Simulation results**

- Type:set
- Location:`/Posts2`
- Data:`{ "key": "value", "uid":"1234few" }`
- Auth: `{ "provider": "google", "uid": "1234few" }`
- Admin: `false`
- Write denied

```
Line 5 (/Posts2)

write: "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current rules specify that you can only write to that location if the data at that location has a child property `'uid'` with the user ID of the current user.

However, what if there is no data at that location? `data.child('uid').val()` will be `null`, which won't match with the current user ID. So we need to first check if the data exists or not, and then check either the existing data or the new data to make sure that the user ID matches.

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Posts2":{
      ".read": true,

      // if the post already exists, the editing user must have a matching user ID
      // if the post doesn't exist, the stored user ID must match the current user
      // allows creation
      ".write": "(data.exists() && data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) || (!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)"
    }
  }
}
```

While the above rules work, they also permit a user to transfer ownership of a post to any other user which could lead to moderation issues. So we should ensure that any new data has a matching user ID regardless of whether the post currently exists or not.

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Posts2":{
      ".read": true,

      // if the post already exists, the editing user must have a matching user ID
      // after the write completes, the stored user ID must match the current user
      // allows creation
      ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && (!data.exists() || data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)"
    }
  }
}
```

The above rules permit a post to be created, but not deleted. If this is also desired, you can now use:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Posts2":{
      ".read": true,

      // if the post already exists, the editing user must have a matching user ID
      // if the post will exist, the editing user must have a matching user ID
      // allows creation and deletion
      ".write": "(!data.exists() || data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) && (!newData.exists() || newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)"
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** Unlike JavaScript, [`==` and `===` are the same operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#_equals) in Realtime Database Security Rules

Comment: Nah! @samethecodingman it's also not working giving the same error of write denied again.

Comment: @Areeb Please add the data & code you are adding to the database that is causing the write error to your question. The rules posted here have been tested to work.

Comment: I am using firebase rules playground and given it already in the question as simulation result

Comment: @Areeb These rules have been tested against the rules playground as you describe. The rules playground will interact with your live database - which suggests that you have a `/Posts2/uid` in your database and it isn't set to `"1234few"`.